# could not resolve property (linq/lambda)

Tags: .net, lambda, linq-to-entities

I am trying to use LINQ/LAMBDA access a property

```
List<Latest> latestBooks = DataContext.Session.Query<Book>().Where(x=> x.Enabled == "True" ).Select(x => new Latest(x.Title,x.Author)).Take(10).ToList();
```

But there is another property defined in the Book class that look like this:

```
public virtual string FrontEndLink { get { return string.Format("http://myurl/{0}", Filename); } }
```

When I try this

```
List<Latest> latestBooks = DataContext.Session.Query<Book>().Where(x=> x.Enabled == "True" ).Select(x => new Latest(x.FrontEndLink)).Take(10).ToList();
```

The code breaks and give me an error:

```
Could not resolve property: Quote((x, ) => (x.Id)), ), Quote((x, ) => (new Latest(x.FrontEndLink, ))), ), p1, )]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LINQ to Entities is trying to convert everything before the `ToList` into SQL - and it won't be able to do that with your `FrontEndLink` property. You want to do that bit in LINQ to Objects, but *after* filtering to only 10 results. So I'd use:

```
var latestBooks = DataContext.Session.Query<Book>()
                             // Do the first bit in the database
                             .Where(x=> x.Enabled == "True")
                             .Take(10)
                             // Do the rest in LINQ to Objects
                             .AsEnumerable()
                             .Select(x => new Latest(x.FrontEndLink))
                             .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks alot Jon for the solution and the clear explanation... thnx